# Java : Unable to convert to Private key inputStream to PrivateKey Object

Tags: java, rsa, inputstream, private-key

I'm trying to convert the input stream of a private key file. This file contains the private key in `byte[]` type and this is present in my file system. This is how I'm reading it as a stream :

```
File file = new File("/home/user/Desktop/user(4).key");
oldPrivateKey = new FileInputStream(file);
```

And this is the method where I'm trying to convert the private key stream to it's object type.

```
public PrivateKey getPrivateKeyObject(InputStream privateKey) throws EmprisException
{
    PrivateKey privateKeyObject = null;
    byte[] privateKeyBytes;
    try {
        privateKeyBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(privateKey);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        privateKeyObject = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
        } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return privateKeyObject;
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting :

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : Short read of DER length
```

What could be the reason for this message?
Would greatly appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably your key is not encoded in pkcs8 format so PKCS8EncodedKeySpec can not load it. Check the format to convert it or use a library like bouncycastle

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday. Did you respond to any of the comments?

Comment: Yes I did, and the previous question wasn't elaborate enough, so I had to delete that. Even if I had edited, it would be too late. Sorry about it.

Comment: @pedrofb yep, I will look into it. Thank you for the response.